# How to lower the case of column names of a data frame but not its values?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

How to lower the case of column names of a data frame but not its values? using RAW Spark SQL and Dataframe methods ?

Input data frame (Imagine I have 100's of  these columns in uppercase)

```
NAME | COUNTRY | SRC        | CITY       | DEBIT
---------------------------------------------
"foo"| "NZ"    | salary     | "Auckland" | 15.0
"bar"| "Aus"   | investment | "Melbourne"| 12.5
```

taget dataframe

```
name | country | src        | city       | debit
------------------------------------------------
"foo"| "NZ"    | salary     | "Auckland" | 15.0
"bar"| "Aus"   | investment | "Melbourne"| 12.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for Java 8

```
Dataset<Row> input;
for (StructField field : input.schema().fields()) {
   String newName = field.name().toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT);
   input = input.withColumnRenamed(field.name(), newName);
   if (field.dataType() instanceof StructType) {
       StructType newStructType = (StructType) StructType.fromJson(field.dataType().json().toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT));
       input = input.withColumn(newName, col(newName).cast(newStructType));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 31):

If you are using *scala*, you can simply do the following

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.select(df.columns.map(x => col(x).as(x.toLowerCase)): _*).show(false)
```

And if you are using *pyspark*, you can simply do the following

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df.select([F.col(x).alias(x.lower()) for x in df.columns]).show()
```

Comment: I am looking for a raw sql solution mainly like `sparkSession.sql("query")`

Comment: @Ramesh Maharjan how to write it using Java?

Comment: Thank You Ramesh. Especially for giving both syntaxes. It helped me first with the Python version, and now I have to rewrite all my code in scala (for production-grade purpose) so the Scala version was really welcome as well

Answer (score 8):

`Java 8` solution to convert the column names to lower case.

```
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column;

df.select(Arrays.asList(df.columns()).stream().map(x -> col(x).as(x.toLowerCase())).toArray(size -> new Column[size])).show(false);
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

Some fake data:

```
scala> val df = spark.sql("select 'A' as AA, 'B' as BB")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [AA: string, BB: string]

scala> df.show()
+---+---+
| AA| BB|
+---+---+
|  A|  B|
+---+---+
```

Now re-select all columns with a new name, which is just their lower-case version:

```
scala> val cols = df.columns.map(c => s"$c as ${c.toLowerCase}")
cols: Array[String] = Array(AA as aa, BB as bb)

scala> val lowerDf = df.selectExpr(cols:_*)
lowerDf: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [aa: string, bb: string]

scala> lowerDf.show()
+---+---+
| aa| bb|
+---+---+
|  A|  B|
+---+---+
```

**Note:** I use Scala. If you use PySpark and are not familiar with the Scala syntax, then `df.columns.map(c => s"$c as ${c.toLowerCase}")` is `map(lambda c: c.lower(), df.columns)` in Python and `cols:_*` becomes `*cols`. Please note I didn't run this translation.

Comment: Why this is not selected as answer since the OP is asking for "raw sql"? I feel this the is the closest to what OP asked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use df.withColumnRenamed(col_name,col_name.lower()) for spark dataframe in python