# How to change column name of database to upper case in Spark using Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I have some column names in mixed cases in my Dataframe like `sum(TXN_VOL)`
I want to convert them to uppercase like `SUM(TXN_VOL)`

I won't be knowing all the column names so I cant convert them using hard coding.

**Either** I have to iterate through all column names and convert each of them to UPPER CASE. **OR** there is any built in functionality to change all column names to UPPER CASE

**What I tried is :**

```
String[] columnNames = finalBcDF.columns();
                    Dataset<Row> x = null;
                    for(String columnName : columnNames) {
                    x = finalBcDF.withColumnRenamed(columnName, columnName.toUpperCase());
                }
```

But this will create new Dataframe each time so, This won't give desired result.

I have checked on many site but I am not able to see how can I do so in Java.

Can anyone help here?

**EDIT**

In one of the answers :

[How to lower the case of column names of a data frame but not its values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48675036/how-to-lower-the-case-of-column-names-of-a-data-frame-but-not-its-values/48677038#48677038)

answer is given for Scala and PySpark but I am not able to convert it to Java, can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can convert the column names to upper case using `Java 8`.

```
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column;

df.select(Arrays.asList(df.columns()).stream().map(x -> col(x).as(x.toUpperCase())).toArray(size -> new Column[size])).show(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterating would be good to go approach. Even though new DataFrame java class instance is created. Since spark evaluated lazily so there will be no performance penalty.

Reference: https://data-flair.training/blogs/apache-spark-lazy-evaluation/